# How to show a Float/Double just like JavaScript literal in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Giving `1.0`, Haskell `show` will get `"1.0"` instead of `"1"`, and use things like `showFFloat` instead of `show` doesn't change that.

This is reasonable since `"1.0"` is more clear to be a Float/Double literal in Haskell, but sometimes I just want a tool function help to show floating point numbers in JavaScript style (which is more natural for human reading).

I mean, round to show the number to specific presision, but without the trailing zeros:

```
showF 1.0 == "1"
showF 1.2 == "1.2"
showF 1.23 == "1.23"
showF 1.00000000001 == "1"
```

---

Now I'm writting this:

```
import Numeric
showF x = let s = showFloat x "" in if ".0" `isSuffixOf` s then take (length s - 2) s else s
```

But it is not very natural, I think there must be a better way.

Comment: Anybody tell me why this question is vote againsted?

Comment: Prior to your first edit, I would have downvoted as well; a downvote indicates a lack of research effort. I think now the question is better, though perhaps no longer on topic, as you are asking for improvements on working code, not a solution to non-working code.

Comment: @chepner I searched a lot to find something like `showFFloat`, I just haven't point this out since it is not related to the problem itself. That doesn't means I'm "lack of research effort",  I think people always can get a working code if pay "enough effort",   But that doesn't means it is the correct way to do things, I can't agree that talking about a "correct way" instead of "make it work" is out of topic...

Comment: @chepner And also, I can remove my own ugly solution to make this question looks like not out of topic, and add some description about my effort, so that's what SO want?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is drop `.0` why not just write a function to do that?

```
dropPointZero :: String -> String
dropPointZero num = if mantissa == ".0" then intPart else num
  where (intPart, mantissa) = break (== '.') num
```

And then combine that with `show` to get what you want.

```
showNum :: (Num a, Show a) => a -> String
showNum = dropPointZero . show
```

This won't work properly if you also wanted to print large values. If you need that, I guess you could just try coercing it to an `Integer` first, and printing the `Integer` if it was one.

```
showFloat :: (Show a, RealFrac a) => a -> String
showFloat x = if fromInteger n == x then show n else show x
  where n = round x
```